# Find the probability of the product of continuous random and an indicator variable

Tags: probability-distributions

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly standard normally distributed, find the $Prob(X\cdot 1_{\{Y\leq c\}} \leq z)$.  Where $1_{\{Y\leq c\}}$ is an indicator variable. c is a constant.

$$P(X\cdot 1_{\{Y\leq c\}} \leq z)=P(X\cdot 1\leq z,Y\leq c) + P(X\cdot 0\leq z,Y\geq c) =P(X\cdot 1\leq z,Y\leq c)\\
  $$

Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by "jointly standard normally distributed" you mean that $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0$, we can compute this probability by conditioning on $Y$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{Y\leqslant c\}}\leqslant z) &= \mathbb P(X\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{Y\leqslant c\}}\leqslant z\mid Y\leqslant c)\mathbb P(Y\leqslant c)\\
&= \mathbb P(X\leqslant z\mid Y\leqslant c)\mathbb P(Y\leqslant c)\\
&= \mathbb P(X\leqslant z)\mathbb P(Y\leqslant c)\\
&= \Phi(z)\Phi(c),
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ denotes the distribution function of a standard normal random variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would it be possible to explain intuitively the first line of your solution -- $\mathbb{P}(X\cdot 1 _{\{Y\leq c\}}  \leq z)= \mathbb{P}(X\cdot1_{\{Y⩽c\}}⩽z∣Y⩽c)\mathbb{P}(Y⩽c)$?

Comment: That is just the definition of conditional probability...